# Why combination of backward FFT(c2r) and forward real-input FFT (r2c) to one complex array doesn't result original complex array?

Tags: fft, fftw, numerical-computing

Real-input FFT is usually expressed `rfft` and inverse is `irfft` in many programming languages (like `python` or `julia`). As [numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.irfft.html) or [julia docs](https://juliamath.github.io/AbstractFFTs.jl/latest/api.html#AbstractFFTs.ifft) said, they are doing normalized FFT not like `FFTW`'s unnormalization FFT

Hence, if I have real input 1D array `a`, I understood `irfft(rfft(a), len(a)) == a`. However, if I assume another 1D array `b` but complex, `rfft(irfft(b), (len(b) - 1) * 2) != b`, even I considered normalization. I think `rfft(irfft(b), (len(b) - 1) * 2)` should be same as `b` like `a`.

I tested this using FFTW by Fortran and Julia's FFTW library but got a same results.

Why this happens? Is this mathematically right or implementation issue?

**EDIT 1:** more exact explanation is [here](https://github.com/JuliaMath/FFTW.jl/issues/29#issuecomment-323067694)

Comment: Because `irfft` and `rfft` only work on the real component of `b`, and ignore the imaginary part. Unless your array `b` has all zero imaginary components?

Comment: Aha! thank you! I removed all imaginary part and then check the results, then it shows same original array (without imaginary part)